# Architecture for temporary storing of values within a javascript library

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I am currently writing a javascript library that wraps a REST API provided by a third party (intended to be used on server side, but wouldn't like to limit it to).  One of the actions defined by the api is 'login' which gives me a session key that I need to use on further requests. Currently, everytime I go to use this library I need to login again as there is no persistence of this session key.  My question is, what is the best way to persist it throughout a session?

My first instinct was to give the library a callback that would store it and a callback that would retrieve it and the implementation can determine how that session key is persisted:

```
var thirdPartyApi = new ThirdPartyApi({ 
    loginCredentials: {..},
    setSessionKeyCallback: function() {},
    getSessionKeyCallback: function() {}
});

thirdPartyApi.makeSomeRequest('foo');
```

Can you recommend the best architecture for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to use the REST Api in a browser. There are some factors you need to take into account, such as, navigating away from the page and coming back to it later.

You can use Web Storage to store the key. There are two types, localStorage and sessionStorage. The only difference between then is that sessionStorage is deleted when the browser window is closed, while localStorage isn't. Web Storage is supported by all modern browsers and IE8+ http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

The localStorage object can be used as such:

```
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);

var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");

localStorage.removeItem("bar");
```

sessionStorage object can be used the same way.

both localStorage and sessionStorage are global objects that can be accessed from anywhere, so there is no need for any special architecture on your ThirdPartyApi object.

Comment: My primary concern is abstraction from the storage engine.  I could use the localstorage global variable within my api but then it's coupled to localstorage.  I don't want to couple my api with any storage engine.

Comment: In this case, you need to have another object that deals with a specific storage technology, and have that object expose a particular interface that your ThirdPartApi object expects. Then pass that storage object to your Api object. In summary, you have to use dependancy injection if you want to generalise your ThirdPartyApi object